# Geocode an address server side in meteor.js and insert coords into the db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, geocoding

I am building a meteor.js app, where I need to geocode addresses into coordinates after or before they are getting inserted into a mongodb collection. This should happen on server side. I thought about using [matb33:collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks). For geocoding I choose to use [node-geocoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder).

I have tried the following, but it only returns undefined. How can I solve this?

```
import NodeGeocoder from "node-geocoder";
import Offers from "../Offers";

Offers.after.insert(((userId, offer) => {
  const geo = NodeGeocoder({
    provider: "google",
    httpAdapter: "https",
    apiKey: "APIKEY",
  });
  const result = geo.geocode(offer.address.street + offer.address.zip + offer.address.city + offer.address.country);

  console.log(result[0]);

  Offers.update({
    _id: offer._id,
  }, {
    $set: {
      "address.lat": result[0].latitude,
      "address.lon": result[0].longitude,
    },
  }, {
    validate: false,
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `offer.address.street + offer.address.zip + offer.address.city + offer.address.country` look like?  I would guess you would need whitespaces between them.